# Create a rounded shape

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I want to create a shape like the image below through xml. Searched a lot to make the corners smooth but not able to make it circular!

[image]

Comment: if You create a ususal shape with corners, and set the width longer than height of the view that has the shape as backround, it will be like this...

Comment: Not possible to do that in xml,  try custom Shape class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:
create a android xml in drawable folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="#96000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: check once its not possible in xml. its not get the exact output.by using canvas it is possible.

Comment: i have tried already. recheck once its not get the exact output.

Comment: thanx dude.i have recheck with mention the size.its works perfectly.

Comment: @NoName i think OP wants the left/right sides to be round regardless the view's height,  your solution works only if views height == 20dp

Comment: Yes this works but need to fix the height. Searching for general solution. Thanks @NoName

Comment: @shailesh general solution is a custom Shape class used with a ShapeDrawable

Comment: @shailesh i posted an example demo link

Answer (score 1):

To complement on @NoName answer, to get the round effect, the height of your shape must equal the radius on each side.

Comment: This is the right answer! I hope others will appreciate it too :)

Answer (score 0):

you create a xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- view background color -->
<solid android:color="#19A347" >
</solid>


<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="2dp" >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" >
</corners>
```